# Can a user send a userOperation transaction without using theirs or any EOA?

Tags: accounts, eoa, erc-4337, account-abstraction

How can a user send a userOperation without having to use an EOA?
Don't get how the EOA is abstracted, unless there is an Executor account signing those userOperations

Answer (score 1):

A user can call a contract that can in turn call a function in another contract. If it is a delegatecall, then the msg.sender would still be the EOA but if it is a regular call, it is technically the intermediary contract making the call.

Answer (score 0):

To send the userOperation on-chain you have to use an EOA because SCW can't initiate a transaction on their own , there must be a EOA which pushes the transaction . If someone wants to do this without using userOps you need to have compatibility of SCW in core layer like `Starknet`.